# How to Handle Pop Up IFrame Window In Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, frame

I am new in Slenium.
[image]

I am trying to handle the pop-up Form.

When I click in New Button the pop-up form like this will open. [image]

I try the handle this by alert(), pop up handling and also by Child Browser Handling. But didn't get the solution.
Please suggest some solution for this issue

Comment: Is this popup an iframe element?

Comment: Yes It seen as a Frame. And when I open It in a new tab it seen as a web page. Having URL like that : www.abc.com/Detail.aspx?type=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an <**iframe**> element then you need to switch WebDriver to this frame in order to work with it. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
By locIframe = By.xpath("//iframe[@name='popup']");
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(locIframe));
// driver is an instance of RemoteWebDriver
```

The Xpath locator is just an example: you need to write your own here. Also you can use any other locator to find that <**iframe**> element in the page source.

After switching to iframe element WebDriver will see it's page source and will be able to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the similar issue. When clicked on `EDIT` Button in the parent window, an iFrame pop-up appears as shown below:`

[image]

As mentioned that you tried to handle using alert() or pop up handling and also by Child Browser Handling. But none of them will work since it is an iFrame pop-up. So you need to switch WebDriver to this frame in order to work with it. 
For my case I did using the following code:

`driver.switchTo().frame(3);`

To find the index of the frame you can use Selenium IDE.